# Treating string literals as constants

Tags: c, gcc

Is there a way to make GCC issue a warning when a string literal is assigned to a non-constant character pointer?

Example:

```
const char *source;
char *target;

target = source;
target = "hello";
```

GCC warns about assigning the constant pointer *source* to the non-constant pointer *target* but the string literal assignment is unfortunately accepted.

Comment: For historical reasons, string literals have type `char[length]`, not `const char[length]`, which is why gcc doesn't warn you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-Wwrite-strings`.  From the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> `-Wwrite-strings`
>
> When compiling C, give string constants the type `const char[length]` so that copying the address of one into a non-`const` `char *` pointer produces a warning.